# When using PayPal's Sandbox what login do I use when it asks me to log in?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing an application that is trying to use Paypal's Express Checkout. After I `SetExpressCheckout` and `"Success"` is returned I redirect to PayPal's Sandbox site with this URL: `return Redirect("http://www.sandbox.paypal.com?cmd=_express-checkout&TOKEN=" + viewModel.Last()["TOKEN"]);`

When I run this from localhost, PayPal says that I need to log in. Now I have a Sandbox login, but I believe I have a Seller test account as well. I think I also need a buyer test account, But whenever I click "New Test Account: Preconfigured" and enter info for a "Buyer" account, it submits but I don't see the new test account anywhere.

So,

A: what login am I supposed to use?

B: where am I supposed to login?

thanks for any help

---

btw:
I know that my initial call to the api is successful:

TOKEN: 
EC-8EB417855U0122113

TIMESTAMP:
2011-05-20T19:42:41Z

CORRELATIONID:
3b01e2f4ae858

ACK:
Success

VERSION:
51.0

BUILD:
1882144

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you're testing the ExpressCheckout functionality, you need to be logged in with your Sandbox account.  The reason is that PayPal needs to be able to figure out which Sandbox account to associate the Checkout with.

Comment: Ok, so just so I understand, 1) I go to my site (in development) 2) I checkout 3) I login with my main sandbox account, 4) then I should be able to checkout?

Comment: Nope nope...the first thing you should do is login with your sandbox account at http://developer.paypal.com/.  Then, can go to your development site and test checkout to your heart's content.

Comment: 1) Logged in at developer.paypal.com 2) went to development site and started the express checkout scripts 3) redirected to sandbox which said "Please login to use the PayPal Sandbox features." 4) clicked the link and it redirected to developer.paypal.com and I'm already logged in... I'm confused. I expected to be redirected to some sort of checkout page, not my account home

Comment: Welcome to coding against PayPal's sandbox. It's often in a wonky-state. But you definitely have the order of operations right.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the help. Should I not use sandbox? I don't have resources lying around to test transactions. Do I wait and hope that Sandbox starts working?

Comment: When I start having problems, I usually clear all cookies from paypal.com and start fresh.  When you log in to developer.paypal.com, they issue a ton of session cookies.  That way, when you land on sandbox.paypal.com while testing your transactions, they know which developer account you're connected to,   which in turns allows you use the fake user accounts you generated.  Make sense?  So you're pretty much stuck doing this.  Whether it works smoothly is another question.  I've had to contact support a number of times to resolve weird issues.

Comment: I tried it in a different browser (to avoid any saved cookies) with no luck

Comment: I have also tried to contact PaPal Customer Support (https://www.x.com/thread/52305?tstart=0) without any luck yet. We'll see.

Comment: Quakkels; ensure you redirect to httpS://www.sandbox...... If you use http:// www.sandbox.. it'll keep asking you to log in to your Developer account.

Comment: oh hey, good call.  the session cookies issued by the sandbox are probably tagged as secure and won't get sent over the non-secure channel.

Comment: @Robert - thanks for the tip and the help on X.com. It is really encouraging that PayPal support staff reacted the way you did.

Comment: For me what solved the problem was to switch from Cassini to IIS 8 Express on Visual Studio.